# QT 5 for android: User-unaccessible place for storing data

Tags: android, qt

My app need to save some important data on android devices, that should NOT be viewed-edited by anyone except me.
Is there such place? 
May be I need to use QSettings - but where it saves data on android phones? Oficial documentation miss part for android platform.
Or android apps have some hidden sandbox? I can use it via JNI.

Comment: You need to switch on iOS. On non-jailbreaked devices inly your application have access to it's own folder. There are no solution for *nix (Android is linux). What is your original task?

Comment: original task to store security info - somewhere where it can't be found.

Comment: And I can't switch to iOs. Its not an option.

Comment: It's impossible to store secure data locally. Please, clarify your task.

Comment: I need to check somehow expiration of trial period of app. And I wanted to save such info locally on device in inaccessibleplace and during app start check: trial period expired or not, time of last app launch, was system clock changed or not and so on

Comment: I understand. It's impossible in common way. But you can think about different tricks, like cookies, file creation time, dynamic compilation (possible will be disabled by antiviruses) and other. Easiest way - use external web server.